# Cluster Queue manager connection issues after cloning for Disaster Recovery?

Tags: ibm-mq

The connection credentials of initial (original box which has been cloned) cluster queue manager keeps on existing in the new cloned box even after deleting the channels.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the issue with more details. It is quite hard to understand what you are saying here.

Comment: You should not delete cluster channels, they should be unclustered first.   Beyond that you mention clone,  if that means an exact file level copy of the qmgrs folder from prod host then that can cause other issues if you are not careful.   Did the CONNAME of the CLUSRCVR stay the same?